# Typeahead Implementation

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead

I've been looking into using typeahead on my php / mysql site. I've got a few versions to work, however I'm still very confused about what to download and what needs to be included to get it to work.

I want to use the newest version of typeahead and haven't found any good explanations on how to get it done. I know the source files are located here (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js), but what exactly do I need?

Comment: read the `readme.md` of that repo

Comment: Do I need the bootstrap.js with the newest version of typeahead.js?

Comment: At the very least you need the jQuery 1.9+ library, plus the typeahead bundle. Once you've referenced these files in your webpage you can then implement a typeahead instance. See the Fiddle referenced in this answer for an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/21533204/203371