# Twitter Typeahead.js Bloodhound remote returns undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

Having trouble getting Twitter Typeahead.js, the remote version to work. I get "undefined" for my suggestions. Any help would be appreciated.

Code below:

JS:

```
var films = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: '../widgets/films.json'
});

films.initialize();

$('#films .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'films',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: films.ttAdapter()
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bloodhound suggestion engine is unable to find the display key "value" within your JSON array.

You need to convert the JSON array into an array of JavaScript objects. The JavaScript objects have a variable called "value", which have a film title as its value; it is this "value" variable which is used by the display key e.g.

```
remote: {
        url: '../widgets/films.json',
        filter: function (films) {
            // $.map converts the JSON array into a JavaScript array
            return $.map(films.results, function (film) {
                return {
                    // NB : replace original_title below with your JSON film key
                    value: film.original_title
                };
            });
        }
    }
```

The example above could be improved if you included a sample of your films.json output (as I'd then be able to use the exact values you need).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21533204/203371) answer for an extended example and jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the help. Answer accepted. Thanks again!