# Typeahed.js not filtering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js

I am using the following code which I based on the examples https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/:

```
var carArray = [{ carId: 1, fullName: 'Opel' }, { carId: 2, fullName: 'BMW' }, { carId: 3, fullName: 'Mercedes' }];
var cars = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('fullName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    //local: carArray,
    remote: '/api/cars'
});

cars.initialize();

$(elt).typeahead(null, {
    name: 'car',
    displayKey: 'fullName',
    source: cars.ttAdapter()
});
```

Uncommenting `local` it works fine, but with `remote` the list does not get filtered, I get all items.

So this is the JSON returned by the `remote`:

`[{"carId":1,"optionOne":"ASD","optionTwo":"QEW","fullName":"Opel"},   {"carId":2,"optionOne":"FAS","optionTwo":"QEW","fullName":"BMW"},{"carId":3,"optionOne":"ADD","optionTwo":"QEW","fullName":"Mercedes"}]`

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Typeahead.js Bloodhound remote returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984508/twitter-typeahead-js-bloodhound-remote-returns-undefined)

Comment: Basically you need to map the JSON array to a JavaScript array. See the question which I have flagged as a duplicate. Adding a filter to your Bloodhound object which will map the JSON appropriately will fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Ben. I followed your suggestion and it does not work. Thank anyway for your input.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser debug console when you are using remote?