# twitter bloodhound engine not working according to twitter-typeahead examples

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I have been using twitter typeahead for quite some time now which is very easy and convenient for my remote data. Now I decided to upgrade to the latest version (typeahead.js 0.10.5) so I could use the robust bloodhound engine. I am having quite some problem with the bloodhound, below is a code I used directly from https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ prefetch example and the code does not seem to work no matter what.

I assume that the `url` that I am calling is correct as the link works fine to me and I see all the countries. The only thing I have changed is `prefetch` to `remote`, it does not work with `prefetch` either. I have also tried other examples on stackexchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530063/how-do-we-set-remote-in-typeahead-js-0-10/21533204#21533204) which works to suggest I am calling my scripts in the header correctly, however when I change the url to the one provided by twitter it does not work. I would like to know if I am using the code I copied from twitter-typeahead examples correctly.

```
    <div id="prefetch">
      <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Countries">
    </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
   var countries = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),       
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      limit: 10,
      remote: {
        // url points to a json file that contains an array of country names, see
        // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json
        url: 'https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json',
        // the json file contains an array of strings, but the Bloodhound
        // suggestion engine expects JavaScript objects so this converts all of
        // those strings
        filter: function (list) {
          return $.map(list, function (country) { 
            return { 
                name: country 
                }; 
            });
        }
      }
    });

    // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
    countries.initialize();

    // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
    // options being used
    $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      name: 'countries',
      displayKey: 'name',
      // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
      // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
      source: countries.ttAdapter()
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the link your provided in `url` is not a json file at all. It's a HTML file. Moreover, that link cannot be used from outside github's domain. You might want to use this url instead https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/typeahead.js/gh-pages/data/countries.json

Comment: Great! one more question, how could you tell it was not a json file? even when I clicked on raw it did not work and it said json at the end of the link extension. Any ways thank you a lot, my mind told me it was the link.

Comment: that's, okay. I'm glad it helped. Since github is not meant to be used as a cdn repo, the mime type with which they send the files is not as per the extension. If you look at chrome developer tools, you will see that any file is sent as text/html. So, you have to use https://rawgit.com/ if you want to use github file for hosting (this is just a fix). It is recommended to use cdn for hosting however