# how to autocomplete bootstrap php mysql ajax from database

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

**autocomplete not working i want fetch data from mysql  database like google  option my file not working not showing any thing when we key down select data from sugested option**

> please sugest some good code
>   my code is  not running 
>   *it is not working now sir*
>   and auto select is not showing similar answer
>   [this is link where showing  but not selecting any data under key selection](http://www.localdp.com/select_autosearch1.php) 
>   [this is link where show nothing](http://www.localdp.com/select_autosearch5.php)

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <!--my file not working auto complete address from database-->
    <!--code inclide file of botstarp -->
<script        
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <!--code of auto fetch-->
      <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#Country').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"autoselect_jquery5.php",
                data:'query=' + query,            
                dataType:"json",
                type:"POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    result($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            });
           }
        });
     });
      </script>
       </head>


       <body>
       div class="container" style="width:600px;">
      <h2 align="center">Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typeahead with Ajax PHP</h2>

                 <label>Search Country</label>
       <input type="text"name="country"id="country"autocomplete="off"placeholder="Country" />
     </div>
 </body>
   <   /html> 

       <!--second file which fetching data from from database -->
     // autoselect_jquery5.php file for fetch code
       <?php
     include 'database.php';

     if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
     $search_query = $_POST['query'];


      $query = "SELECT * FROM transporter WHERE address LIKE 
  '%".$search_query."%' LIMIT 12";
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  $data = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
   {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
        $data[] = $row["address"];
     }
      echo json_encode($data);
          }
      }
       ?>




    }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing bootstrap and jquery? Both are completely different things.

Comment: thanks sir  please suggest me how  to run code it is not working

Answer (score 0):

for autocomplete, you can use typehead.js its works with the bootstrap check below ex.

[How do we set remote in Typeahead.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530063/how-do-we-set-remote-in-typeahead-js)

Answer (score 0):

You have some wrongs, I explain you in the comments in your code.

I hope that I can help you. I copied your code and I fixed it.

It is working now. Try it and comment me.

Steps:

1) Import the database file (on your local server).

Link database: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1JhXXPQ4QHsHssTbpdnhL_cBOrnK7Q3nB

2) Copy in a folder of local server the file autocomplete.html.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <!--my file not working auto complete address from database-->
    <!--code inclide file of botstarp -->
<script        
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <!--code of auto fetch-->
      <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#country').typeahead({ // Your #Country ID is different that you using in input 
        // #Country <> 
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"database.php",
                data:'query=' + query,            
                dataType:"json",
                type:"POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    result($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            });
           }
        });
     });
      </script>
       </head>


       <body>
       <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
      <h2 align="center">Autocomplete Textbox using Bootstrap Typeahead with Ajax PHP</h2>

                 <label>Search Country</label>
       <input type="text"name="country"id="country"autocomplete="off"placeholder="Country" />
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

3) Copy in same folder the php code.

```html
<?php  
 
 $host = 'localhost'; //This is your host, if you working locally your host will be localhost
 $user = 'root'; //The name of the your user in localhost server
 $pass = 'root'; //The password of the your user in localhost server
 $db_name = 'countries'; //The name of the database that you using

 $keyword = strval($_POST['query']); // 
 $search_param = "{$keyword}%";
 $conn =new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

 $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM country WHERE name LIKE ?");
 $sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);   
 $sql->execute();
 $result = $sql->get_result();
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $countryResult[] = $row["name"];
  }
  echo json_encode($countryResult);
 }
 $conn->close();
?>
```

4) It's over.